# Alexa Error "The following directives are not supported: DelegateDirective" after Connections.Response purchaseResult

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit

- I am using ISP (In skill purchase) and after the whole cycle of purchasing Alexa handle the control back to the skill backend.
- So I get a `Connections.Response` with `purchaseResult:ACCEPTED`
- Now I send a Delegate Directive to an Intent to collect a number

  ```
   return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .addDelegateDirective(myVoiceSelectionIntent)
          .getResponse();
  ```
- Now I got the following error:

  ```
    "error": {
        "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
        "message": "The following directives are not supported: DelegateDirective"
  ```

**What I tried**

- I added the same code snipped to an other intent of the skill and I get forwarded to the *myVoiceSelectionIntent*
- I tried to return speech and prompt as well but same error.

**Question**

- Is not possible to use intent chaining and send DelegateDirectives from a `Connections.Response` with `purchaseResult:ACCEPTED`?
- I could not find anything that it's forbidden in the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/in-skill-purchase/add-isps-to-a-skill.html#handle-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the [amazon developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/233922/alexa-error-the-following-directives-are-not-suppo.html) as well after nobody replied and it's not possible yet after a *Connections.Response*

> Jason@amazon:
> This is a current limitation of intent chaining - you won't be able to
> use it with any Connections.Response request that comes into your
> skill